# Continuous but not of finite $p$ variation for any $p$

Tags: real-analysis

I know examples of functions that are continuous but not $\alpha$-Holder for any $\alpha$. For example $f(x):=1/\ln(x)$ for $x>0$ and $f(0):=0$. I know of examples of functions that are continuous but not bounded variation. For example $f(x):=\sqrt x$.

But what about continuous and not bounded $p$-variation for any $p$?